# How to find the basic block given an instruction location in that basic block?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

Suppose I have an instruction location. I would like to find the basic block that contains that instruction. Let's define "basic block" as the instruction location for the entry point into the basic block that contains the desired instruction. Assume that I have any form of address space randomization disabled, so all program sections and libraries get loaded to the same locations in virtual address space whenever the program is executed. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: This seems like it would be platform specific.  The answer is going to be different depending on whether you are using Windows or Posix, for example.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by virtual address space.  In fact the entire question is a bit hypothetical.

Comment: Did you mean « *the section the contain this instruction* » ?

Comment: To locate "the basic block that **contains** that instruction" you need to scan backwards (the instruction may not be at the very start of a block). Scanning backwards is close to impossible; it's not "platform specific", it's **CPU** specific. Even when using a CPU with 'easy' assembler -- all opcodes in the regular execution space of an ARM are 4 bytes long -- you cannot say if you're backing into a data area. And you cannot know where the block begins without disassembling the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely difficult question. In fact, you cannot even hope to know where are the basic blocks for the general case at the assembly level.

The problem comes from the fact that assembly is a *jump based language* and, by definition a basic block is a sequence of instructions where no jump does land.

Even if you executed 99% of the program, you can never know if the last instruction will not land in the middle of something that you believed to be a basic block. And, of course, I am speaking about only ONE EXECUTION, but this should be looked at for ANY EXECUTION.

So, finding the CFG of a binary program (and thus its basic blocks) is something which is as hard as the halting problem (see Turing diagonal argument).

You should maybe try to give more details about what you really need, because the general question, as you stated it, is simply not possible.

Comment: I don't think you know the definition of a basic block.  A BB starts at a jump target and continues either to the instruction before the next jump target or to a jump instruction.

Comment: This is definitely not my definition, nor the one that people are using in static analysis... You may find useful to read [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) (Wikipedia) which states that no jump come into the block between the start of the basic block and then end of the basic block.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this under restrictive assumptions.

First, the code can't be self-modifying in any general sense.  This would make the problem undecidable.

Second, you need a complete list of jump targets.  Certainly debugging information will include this.  But if you don't have debugging information, it's still possible to deduce much by disassembling, finding all branch and jump instructions, and taking their immediate targets. Jump tables implementing `switch` are also useful.  A hard case will be function pointers. Good reverse engineering tools do this quite well: disassemble code when little is known about its structure.  On the other hand, they can't be perfect: interspersed data and code can always be confused with each other.

Third, you'll need a list of all jump/branch instruction addresses in the program.

With these lists in hand, you'r good to go.  Each basic block starts with a jump target and runs either to the instruction before the next target or to a jump/branch instruction (inclusive), whichever comes first.  An algorithm that accepts an instruction address and searches the lists for the associated block beginning and end is straightforward.

Actually, it's simplest to merge the lists into a single one and use binary search.  The entries before and after the searched address define the block it lies in.

Comment: The code does not even need to be self-modifying to make it undecidable... Extracting all paths from a binary is already linked to the halting problem.

Comment: @perror That's just wrong.  If you can disassemble a program and the branch targets are static, then you can compute the flow graph of basic blocks.  "Linked to the halting problem" is not an undecidability proof.

Comment: The branches are not all static... You should read a bit of assembler from time to time, it might help.

Comment: @perror I've coded and read many thousands of lines of assembler and written compilers.  Branch instructions don't move themselves.  You should read the definition of basic blocks and flow graphs. Aho Sethi, and Ullman _Compiler Design_ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to happen:

- You need to keep debug information containing the mapping
- The optimization level must be low enough for this to be unambiguous.

In short, you need support from your toolchain, even more so if you actually want to have more information than an instruction pointer where a new variable goes live, without any information about the variable.